# Reading subkeys of HKEY_CURRENT_USER from Registry returns HKEY_USERS subkeys value

Tags: c#, windows, registry

In c#, I tried to read the values of short date format from the Windows registry in HKEY_CURRENT_USER but instead I get the values from HKEY_USERS.

I used the following codes to read the subkeys of HKEY_CURRENT_USER

```
    RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\International\");
    var DateFormat = RegKey.GetValue("sShortDate");
```

How do I get the HKEY_CURRENT_USER subkey values?

Comment: This needs clarification.  What values did you get, and what values did you expect to get?  What makes you think there is a problem?

Comment: I changed the date format to dd-MM-yyyy  and it can be seen in HKEY_CURRENT_USER but in HKEY_USERS, the date format still in dd/MM/yyyy. I need to get this format dd-MM-yyyy by using the above code. Is there any other way to get it?

Comment: There is no such key as `HKEY_USERS\Control Panel`, what is the actual path to the key that contains the old `dd/MM/yyyy` value?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the correct values.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is just an alias for `HKEY_USERS\<sid_of_current_user>`, where  changes depending on who is logged in.  So any time you get a key

```
HKCU\key\subkey\value
```

Windows internally rewrites it to be

```
HKEY_USERS\<sid_of_current_user>\key\subkey\value
```

The `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` registry hive is just a convenient shortcut provided by Windows, because it's so useful to get the keys for the currently logged in user.